# Limit Text and make sure there are no tags open

Tags: php, truncate

So i have a list of articles, and I have a page in which shows 4 articles at a time and then shortens the description of the article to 1000 characters and allows users to "read more", my problem is within each post there could be tags IE: `<i>` or `<b>` `<img>` `<center>` etc, how when truncating the text can I see if there are any open tags within the div or within the called upon text?

Here is how it looks for now

```
$sum = strip_tags($article, '<a><i><b><u><center><br><img><a><span><iframe>');
    if (strlen($sum) > 1000) {
        $sumCut = substr($sum, 0, 1000);
        $sum = substr($sumCut, 0, strrpos($sumCut, ' ')).'... <div class="right"><a href="article-' .$record[nid]. '">Read More</a></div>'; 
}

 echo $sum;
```

For example

If I have...

*Quisque imperdiet imperdiet fringilla. Quisque sit amet nibh odio. Fusce sit amet massa vitae mi faucibus viverra.*

The code fo that would be `<i>Quisque imperdiet imperdiet fringilla. Quisque sit amet nibh odio. Fusce sit amet massa vitae mi faucibus viverra.</i>`

but if I were to set my truncating number to say 10, it would leave that tag open and thus everything afterwords would be in italics

Comment: What exactly do you mean by seeing if there are open tags?

Comment: Ill update to explain...

Comment: I thought you stripped all the tags though.

Comment: except for the tags that I allow `<a><i><b><u><center><br><img><a><span><iframe>`

Comment: I posted something you can build off of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), search for open tags within the first X characters (where X is the truncating number.) Then if true, add to a string.

Basically, (pseudocode)

```
if(first10chars.contains[use strpos here] "<i>" and !.contains "</i>") {
$endstr .= "</i>";
}
```

and do the same for the others. A pretty bad way but it'll work

Comment: That got me on the right track, I also answered with the end solution I came up with

Comment: Alright, thank you for doing that, most users don't and it leaves people with the same problem behind :P

Answer (score 2):

so dynamic got me close, but using `strpos()` was the key, I added this to my code `if ((strpos($sum, '<i>')) && (!strpos($sum, '</i>'))) { echo "</i>"; }` and one similar for each tag that I allow, next thing to do is to figure out how to make sure that there are no images or iframes near the end of the post, I will edit this to explain how I did that, but for now here is my code...

```
$sum = strip_tags($article, '<a><i><b><u><center><br><img><a><span><iframe>');
if (strlen($sum) > 1000) {
    $sumCut = substr($sum, 0, 1000);
    $sum = substr($sumCut, 0, strrpos($sumCut, ' '));
    $cut = 1; 
}else{
    $cut = 0; }

echo $sum;
if ((strpos($sum, '<i>')) && (!strpos($sum, '</i>'))) { echo "</i>"; }

if ($cut==1) { echo '... <div class="right"><a href="article-' .$record[nid]. '">Read More</a></div>'; }
```

**EDIT:**

Okay, I figured out a better solution than making sure there were no images at the end of the post, I simply made the divs `overflow: hidden;` in which it would resize for the images

**EDIT:**

I also had an issue with breaking the middle of a `<br>` tag, it was leaving me with `<br` a temporary fix seems to be to add another `<br>` after everything which in these cases leaves the bad code `<br<br>` but atleast everything works and isnt visible, but if anybody has a more viable solution please let me know

I hope this helps